# Real analysis: calculating square root

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1 = 2.\quad$ Define $x_{n+1} = (x_n + 2/x_n)/2.\quad$ Show that $x_n^2$ is always greater than $2$, and then use this to prove $x_n - x_{n+1} \ge 0.\quad$ Conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Done.  What's next?

Comment: What did you try about ?.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x+ \frac{2}{x})$. Note that $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and so $f$ has a minimum on $(0,\infty)$. Differentiating and setting $f'(\hat{x}) = 0$ yields $\hat{x} = \sqrt{2}$, and $f(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2}$, so we have $f(x) \ge \sqrt{2}$ for all $x >0$.

Furthermore, since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{2}{x^2})$, we see that $f'(x) \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ for all $x \ge \sqrt{2}$. Hence $f$ is a contraction mapping on $[\sqrt{2}, \infty)$.

Since $x_1 \in [\sqrt{2}, \infty)$, we see that $x_n$ converges to the unique fixed point of $f$. Checking $x = f(x)$, we see that this has the solution $x = \sqrt{2}$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is:
$$ x_{n+1}^2 = \frac{1}{4}(x_n^2+4+\frac{4}{x_n^2}) \geq \frac{x_n^2}{4}+1$$
And I think you can continue from here with induction.

Also, you can see that $$x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2 = 1+\frac{1}{x_n^2}-\frac{3}{4}x_n^2 $$
Since $x_n^2\geq 2$ you conclude that $x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2 \leq 0$ and finish the second part.

For the third part, you now know that $\{x_n\}$ is monotonic and limited from below by $\sqrt{2}$.