# Let $a_{n}$ be the sequence defined inductively by $a_{1} = 2$ and $a_{n+1} = 1/2 ( a_n + 2/a_n)$. Prove this sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence

I have already inductively proven that $a_n∈[1,2]$ and found that $(a_{n})^2⩾2$ for all $n ∈ N$ I think I need to prove that the sequence converges to the greatest lower bound root 2 but i havent a scooby how to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real analysis: calculating square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539828/real-analysis-calculating-square-root) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665029/let-x-1-2-and-define-x-n1-frac1-2-x-n-frac-2-x-n?rq=1)? or [many others...](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%20%2B%202%2Fa_n%7D2%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have $$(a_n)^2\ge2$$

Dividing by $2a_n$ since we know it is positive we get
$${a_n\over 2}\ge{1\over a_n}\\a_n\ge{a_n\over 2}+{1\over a_n}\\a_n\ge a_{n+1}$$

Which shows it is decreasing

Comment: Fine, but please don't edit a (necessarily duplicate) answer to such a FAQ.

Comment: goddamn ur smart